# createTextFinder with getCurrentMatch() GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I wan't find row index of value. In sheet have value but result return is null.

[image: data like this]

```
  function testFindRowIndex(){

  var id = 'ID00002';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(IDDBSYS);
  var wsRole = ss.getSheetByName("Roles");
  var index = wsRole.createTextFinder(id).getCurrentMatch().getRowIndex();
  Logger.log(index);

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should start the search first using [`findNext()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createTextFinder(String)):

```
wsRole.createTextFinder(id).findNext().getRowIndex();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. If data have only one "ID00002" I think it work but in this my case may be result return random column D because this column have "ID00002". I understand that, right? Can you explain help me?

Comment: @Naoa I don't understand. Are you looking for [`findAll`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder.html#findAll())?

Comment: @Master Thanks for answering. I know findAll and findNext but How is getCurrentMatch() used? I'm try use it. I think getCurrentMatch() return exactly index of value

Comment: @Naoa After you do `findNext()`, you can use `getCurrentMatch()`. Both returns `range` objects. The first one returns the  next range, the last one returns the current range

Comment: @Master Thanks for answering. Yes i know but when i use getCurrentMatch() returns is "null". I don't know where I make mistakes?

Comment: @Naoa You must use `findNext()` first. This is similar to the "Find and replace" in the Google sheets UI. You enter the search term and then you click find first. After finding the first term, you can get the currentMatch highlighted and therefore used.